# Joining fields which must still be created in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-joins

I am in the process of creating a **generic** model in ArcGIS Model Builder. At one point in my model, I have to do a join between an existing layer (entry parameter) and a table issued from the "Zonal Statistics as table" tool.

I get an error when I launch the model from the Toolbox, as the field to do the join doesn't exist. When I create a "Zone field", "Input join field" and "Output join fields" as parameters, I can get the fields to be defined by the user. However, he has to write the name of the "Zone field".

Is it possible to select that value in a list (like the fields from my existing layer)?

If I am doing things wrong, how can I get the model to say which fields to do the join on?

One layer is a .shp that is defined as a parameter. The other is a layer produced by a raster calculator in the geodatabase then reclassed and to which a "Zonal Statistics as table" was applied.

Version 1 that returns an error:

[image: Here is a view]

Version 2 that works, but doesn`t enable the user to pick the field the join needs to be on in a list:

[image]

Comment: What type of data is your layer?  Is one input a feature class from a geodatabase and another as a .shp?

Comment: check whether changing the environmental settings between the use of qualified and unqualified field would resolve the problem

Comment: I think I am missing something here... Is it important for the user to be able to select the join field? If the user can already select the zone field, this should be the same for the join?

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me as well. I just run the model to that point. Then I select the join fields and run again. Ensure Geoprocessing options > overwrite is one and that seems to work. It then works always going forward.